# Taking storage from swap and adding to LVM

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

My current output of

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              20G  2.1G   17G  11% /
tmpfs                  64G     0   64G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             194M   54M  131M  30% /boot
```

I do not need 64GB of swap/temp space. Is it possible to reduce that storage and add it to LVM?

/dev/sda5 to be precise

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26        2637    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            2637        3681     8388608   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4            3681      116476   906025984    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            3681      116476   906024960   8e  Linux LVM
```

Any help would be appreciated. OS is Centos 6 64bit

Thanks

Comment: what you can is reduce the size of your swap volume. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmpfs` is a filesystem created from virtual memory and not physical disk space. So in this instance you will not be able to use that "free space".